# Content Editor toolbar is not displaying in ADX Portal

Tags: javascript, crm, adxstudio-portals

What could be the reason why the Content Editor Toolbar of ADX Portal is not displaying, We recently published our code but then the editor toolbar is not displaying, we reverted our codes to the previous one but the same issue still occurs, while inspecting the html element the class "yui-panel-container" is there but the visibility is hidden, we change the visibility of it to visible but still there's no content.

What should be done to fix this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the issue even after reverting your code, it makes me believe your web page access rules were changed.You must change permissions to grant on the page you want the content editor to show up.

Answer (score 0):

In Administrator Web Role, make sure the target contacts are included.

[image]

Also, make sure **Grant Change to Administrators** is included in **Web Page Access Control Rules**.

[image]

Finally, in **Grant Change to Administrators**, make sure all required fields are filled in.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

hi associate a web role to the user and then if you have created any business flow for your form in CRM , make sure to remove it and try again.